# Why this for loop does not stop

Tags: c++, loops, infinite

I have been looking at this code for 20min and I can't understand why this loop is infinite, it should print 30 elements.

Some text, because post is mostly code.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: `if (i = 1){` you probably meant `if (i == 1){`

Comment: The question demonstrates why compiler warnings should not be ignored

Comment: 'I have been looking at this code for 20min'.   Really, how impressive. Please learn how to debug before you write another line of code.  SO is already flooded with posts from people who can code OK, but cannot develop software because they don't have the full skillset rquired to progress beyond 'Hello World'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because `if (i = 1)` assigns `1`to`i`. You meant to compare`if (i == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake when programming in C(++), early on, people mistake the equality operator `==` with the assignment operator `=`.

What you're doing here with the line `if (i = 1){` is setting `i` to 1 on each iteration of  the loop, so i never gets any larger.
To fix it, simply change that line to `if (i == 1) {`

Answer (score 0):

the if statement is wrong. it should be

```
if(i == 1)
```

currently on each loop you are assigning i back to 1. Hence the reason why the loop is infinite